# How to generate table definitions using JPA Tools with Eclipselink 2.5

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I tried to set-up tables in a MySql database with MySql Workbench including foreign keys, unique indexes, cascades on update/delete, ...
Then I let Eclipselink 2.5.1 create entities from tables with Project --> JPA Tools... in Eclipse. My hope was to see how I have to annotate classes, fields, methods to get the same result if I define the objects and run JPA Tools the other way around (Create Tables from Entities...).

Unfortunately I can't see anything of the previously defined cascading options or indexes in the created Java classes. Is there a way to make this way work?

For instance, I want to know how I can define the cascading option for update a I can do with *@CascadeOnDelete* (in MySql On Update stays 'RESTRICT')...or to find out why

```
@Table(name="geolocations", 
   uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"latitude", "longitude"}))
```

does not result in an index creation in the MySql table after running JPA Tools --> Create Tables form Entities...

Comment: EclipseLink has an index annotation for defining indexes, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Indexes  As for pulling in database cascade options from your tables - these are custom EclipseLink annotations that do not seem built into the Dali JPA tooling.  You may need to file a feature request with Dali to have support added.